# Появление прокрутки при верстке

Tags: css3, html, css, bootstrap

Скачал тренировочный шаблон для верстки, (при верстке использовал **бутстрап сетки**) столкнулся с проблемой, **появление пустого пространства в браузере и прокрутка** - вообщем всё можно увидеть на скрине - *http://prntscr.com/66xv1j*(на нем можно заметить, то, что я выделил через файрбаг весь html  Какие причины послужили образованию такого пространства?

Comment: ссылка на страницу есть?

Comment: к сожалению нету, это обычная страничка тренировочная(

Answer (score 1):

проблема была в том что я использовал больше чем 12 блоков, и делал сдвиг, например

> class="col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-1"